# UFW Blocking FTP Access

Tags: debian, ftp, iptables, ufw, proftpd

I have installed UFW on debian and now my FTP server is not working whenever I connect to it using a client, it allows me to log in and lists my home directory, but whenever I try to navigate somewhere else it just hangs.

I've solved the issue by setting ProFTPD to use passive ports and allowed my port range within UFW, everything now works like it did before.

However, I'm having a hard time searching to find out why this is the case and why passive ports solves the problem. Would anyone be able to explain why UFW blocks FTP access when its enabled and why using passive ports solves my problem, I don't want to continue with out knowing why this works?

Comment: In short: FTP is a terrible protocol to get through firewalls since it uses connections with dynamic endpoints and these information get exchange at the application level. For deeper details see http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-ftp-port-requests-challenge-firewall-security/

Comment: [This article](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html) does a good job of describe FTP active _vs_ passive data transfers, and their complications/interactions with firewalls.

Comment: In order to figure out why, need to see if your firewall settings are the culprit. I have same configuration with zero problems.

Comment: I recommend posting the output of the following: `sudo ufw status numbered`.  Also when using client in active mode check the print the ufw logs eg `sudo tail /var/log/ufw.log`